# How to navigate back to parent URL after loading a new Url inside my custom plugin?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a custom Cordova plugin which loads a new URL. When I try to navigate back to the app from my plugin, it shows the error as mentioned in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur2rn.jpg